# Call a function when select box changes its value and when remains same

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have multilpe select dropdowns and all have same class, I want to trigger a function on change of any of select dropdown and also trigger a another function when the values are remains unchanges.

Suppose I have 3 dropdowns user changes any one dropdown option then I need to call a function, in the same way if user keeps options back to unchanged then I need to call another function. For example I have 3 dropdowns user comes and changes first dropdown to redeem offer then I will call a function but if that user keeps same value which initially that dropdown had say select offer then I need to call a function.

here is what I tried so far

JS code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".gift-sts").on('change', function() {
            if ($('.gift-sts').val() == 'Open'){
                stsUnChanged();
            } else {
               stsChanged();
            }
        });

      function stsChanged(){
            $('.save-order-sts').removeClass('btn-primary');
            $('.save-order-sts').addClass('btn-success');
            $('.save-order-sts').attr('disabled',false);    
      }
      function stsUnChanged(){
            $('.save-order-sts').addClass('btn-primary');
            $('.save-order-sts').removeClass('btn-success');
            $('.save-order-sts').attr('disabled',true);    
      }
    })
```

Here is what I have in my html

```
<button class="save-order-sts">Save</button>

<select name="" class="gift-sts" id="gift_!">
   <option value="Open">Open</option>
   <option value="Redeem">Redeem</option>
   <option value="Cancel">Cance</option>
 </select>
 <select name="" class="gift-sts" id="gift_2">
   <option value="Open">Open</option>
   <option value="Redeem">Redeem</option>
   <option value="Cancel">Cance</option>
 </select>
 <select name="" class="gift-sts" id="gift_3">
   <option value="Open">Open</option>
   <option value="Redeem">Redeem</option>
   <option value="Cancel">Cance</option>
 </select>
```

**So basically if any one of above dropdown value changes then I will call stsChanged function else if values of all three dropdown remains same then I will trigger stsUnChanged(). Can anybody help me with this? Thanks in advance.**

**Fiddle to try [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ng0hfa9c/)**

Comment: is the default value **always** "Open" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to check if any of the 3 select has not the default value

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".gift-sts").on('change', function() {
    var isChanged = selectChanged();
    isChanged ? stsChanged() : stsUnChanged();
  });

  //this function will check if any of the 3 select changed
  function selectChanged(){
   var changed = false;
    $('.gift-sts').each(function(){
        if ( $(this).val() !== "Open" ) changed = true;
    });
    return changed;
  }

  function stsChanged(){
    $('.save-order-sts').removeClass('btn-primary');
    $('.save-order-sts').addClass('btn-success');
    $('.save-order-sts').attr('disabled',false);    
  }
  function stsUnChanged(){
    $('.save-order-sts').addClass('btn-primary');
    $('.save-order-sts').removeClass('btn-success');
    $('.save-order-sts').attr('disabled',true);    
  }
});
```

see this [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/LuL11b7v/)

---

Update

If your default value is variable you need to store it somewhere. You can use a data attribute:

```
$('.gift-sts').each(function(){
  $(this).data("default-value", $(this).val());
});
```

then compare the current value with the default one:

```
if ( $(this).val() !== $(this).data("default-value") ) changed = true;
```

that's it! [UPDATED DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/LuL11b7v/4/)

Comment: Great! Thanks...Please add css to you fiddle and update so others who need this will help them

Comment: is it possible to check with all previous values that dropdown had selected other than 'open'? lets say I have redeem selected for one dropdown and open for other but on change of any dropdown value I need to call save button?

Comment: sure, but you need few changes. i'll update the answer right now

Comment: @SudarshanKalebere check out

Comment: I cant assign data-attr but I have selected value for each select box

Comment: @SudarshanKalebere in that case do it with jQuery. Check updated answer and see an example here: https://jsfiddle.net/LuL11b7v/4/

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `this` instead of `.gift-sts` in your callback to reference the element:

```
$(".gift-sts").on('change', function() {
    if( $(this).val() == 'Open' ) {
        stsUnChanged();
    } else {
        stsChanged();
    }
});
```

And you know that you can chain actions?

```
function stsChanged() {
    $('.save-order-sts').removeClass('btn-primary')
                        .addClass('btn-success')
                        .attr('disabled', false);    
}

function stsUnChanged() {
    $('.save-order-sts').addClass('btn-primary')
                        .removeClass('btn-success')
                        .attr('disabled', true);    
}
```

Comment: I tried with this also please read my post, any one dropdown changed then I have to call stsChanged else stsUnChanged. suppose if I change sts of dropdown 1 & dropdown 2 , then I will call changed function but in the meanwhile if I change sts of dropdown 2 and keep it as earlier to open then I still need to call changed only because one more dropdown  is open.

Comment: I mean to say whenever all dropdowns are at unchanged i,e to open selected then I need to call stsUnchanged(), else if any one is changed then I will call stsChanged();

Answer (score 0):

Problem is, you can't use class name to get value of the drop down list, because you are having more than one list with same class name, so you have to use id for each of the list, or you can simply use 'this' keyword to get the current object.
So the code will be like,

```
if ($(this).val() == 'Open'){
        stsUnChanged();
   } else {
        stsChanged();
   }
```

Now this will work fine I guess...

Comment: Hi @Ruwaid thanks for the reply but see above I got it, pumpkinzzz did it. But really thanks that you tried to answer :-) happy coding.